# I want to group the cars by their type in this associative array.- PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I just want to group this arrays from this:

```
["2019 Honda Civic" => "Sedan", 
 "Maruti Suzuki Baleno" => "Hatchback",  
 "Rolls-Royce Phantom" => "Sedan"]
```

to this

```
["Sedan" => ["2019 Honda Civic", "Rolls-Royce Phantom"], 
 "Hatchback" => ["Maruti Suzuki Baleno"]]
```

```
<?php
function groupByType($cars) {
       return; 
}

$cars= ["2019 Honda Civic" => "Sedan", "Maruti Suzuki Baleno" => "Hatchback",  "Rolls-Royce Phantom" => "Sedan"];
$groups = groupByType($cars);
var_dump($groups);
```

Comment: This needs more code `function groupByType($cars) {
       return; 
}`

Comment: How is the array generated in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a combination of `array_*` functions that could achieve this as well, but you could just loop the array, and flip the values - grouping by the old value (new key), as shown below.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if (!isset($result[$v]))
        $result[$v] = [$k];
    else 
        $result[$v][] = $k;
}
return $result;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/o336l

Comment: It is working but It's a little bit messy but I'll try to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily flip your array with [array_flip()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-flip.php) and then do a little housekeeping.
Check out a demo here: https://eval.in/1091512

```
$cars= ["2019 Honda Civic" => "Sedan", "Maruti Suzuki Baleno" => "Hatchback",  "Rolls-Royce Phantom" => "Sedan"];

$groups = array_flip($cars);

foreach ($groups as $g => $c)
    $groups[$g] = implode(", ", array_keys($cars, $g));
```

Comment: This creates an array of strings rather than an array of arrays.